# Android Check if banner is pressed

Tags: java, android, touch, listener

I'm trying to find a method to check if a banner (ad) is checked, but it is more difficult that it seams.

I tried

```
adView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //TODO
        }
    });
```

But it doesn't work(i put a debug print but it didn't work..)

Then i tried to create a LinearLayout that wraps the adView and putted the listener on the linear layout, but it still didn't work.

Then i tried to create a bigger layout that contained all the display, and added the adView in it. I thought to put a onTouchListener in it, and checking the coordinates, to check if the add was pressed. But i don't really understand the how to find the correct coordinates of my banner (i created a method that gets x and y offset and the gravity to use to place the banner) to check, and i really hope that a better way exists. In addition i found that the method is not executed if i press the banner, but only if other parts of the screen are pressed.

So, is there some way to know it? I don't care to know if the banner page was loaded, or if it redirected to the market or the browser, i just need to know if the banner was pressed.

Maybe setting a check that runs when the screen is touched, and than check if the listner method was run, and if it wasn't run that the banner was touched can work, but i don't know how to implement it..

Any idea how to do this?

Thank you

Comment: I think you just add an `OnTouchListener` to the ad banner. When `onTouch` is called, it's been clicked. No need to check the coords.

Comment: @stevehb  
Have you tried it? On my side i've already tried it and it didn't work.. And probably it is because the touch is passed to the activity that handles the banner, and that doesn't provide any callbacks for touch inputs

Comment: I've had trouble before by adding `OnClickListener` to a view instead of `OnTouchListener`. The click listener never got input, but the touch one did, and I thought that might be your problem. Also, I don't think the `Activity` does any input handling. It would be easier to figure out if you could post a sample activity that loads the banner view, adds the touch listener, and is still unresponsive.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why other people haven't spoken about which adView you are using?
Most (like in all I know) provide a listener you can supply, that has a callback for when a ad is clicked.

MobFox for example has `setBannerListener(BannerListener listener)` and that listener has a method `adClicked()`. Other providers (like admob, inmobi, mopub) all have similar listeners you can set.

That should be the way to handle this, not hacking into a containerview.

Answer (score 1):

For those who still didnt know how to:

Its using AdListener

```
adView.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
            public void onDismissScreen(Ad arg0) {
               Toast.makeText(BannerAdListener.this, "Back to app", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            public void onFailedToReceiveAd(Ad arg0, ErrorCode arg1) {
               Toast.makeText(BannerAdListener.this, "Error loading", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

            public void onLeaveApplication(Ad arg0) {
               Toast.makeText(BannerAdListener.this, "Left app", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

            public void onPresentScreen(Ad arg0) {
               Toast.makeText(BannerAdListener.this, "Sumthin sumthin", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

            public void onReceiveAd(Ad arg0) {
               Toast.makeText(BannerAdListener.this, "Ad Received", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try putting a toast in your click event?

Does the app compile and run?

Do you have duplicate ids ?

Comment: I put a debug print that never show in the logcat. Would it be different if i put a toast? I don't think.. The code is simply not executed..

Yes, it runs fine, except that the onClickListener is never called

The view is created at runtime, so no id is present.

Comment: You opened your post 

I'm trying to find a method to check if a banner (ad) is checked

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i solved, and since i lost quite a bit of time to find the solution, i post it here so that everyone can find and use it!

```
LinearLayout containAdView = null;

    if(registerTouch)
    {
            containAdView = new LinearLayout(pActivity){

            public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev)
            {
                if(ev.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
                {
                    bannerClicked(pActivity, shared_Prefs_name, shared_Save_name);

                    if(mainMenu.ISDEV)
                    {
                        final Toast tost = Toast.makeText(pActivity, "Banner Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                        tost.show();
                    }
                }

                return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev);
            }
        };
        containAdView.addView(adView, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    }
```